# Metric Math - SUM dynamics metrics to impact autoscale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have an autoscale group that would normally have 2 instances in it, but I wish to scale up based on a custom metric (*item_count*). My scale up formula I wish to use is is `instance count * threshold > total item count`, i.e. if the item count was 35 and 30 respectively, instance count was 2 and threshold was 30, the total item count exceeds the threshold and a CloudWatch alarm should go off, triggering an autoscale action.

I believe this is possible using custom metrics in CloudWatch. I've modified my `amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json` file as follows:

```
  "metrics":{
    "namespace": "Custom",
    "metrics_collected":{
       "statsd":{
          "service_address":":8125",
          "metrics_collection_interval":5,
          "metrics_aggregation_interval":10
       }
    }
  }
```

To test, I've been running a simple local echo test on each machine:

Server 1:

`echo "item-count:35|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125`

Server 2:

`echo "item-count:30|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125`

My metrics are reporting back to CloudWatch and I've been able to write a "metric math" to SUM these values together. However I am unable to write a "metric math" expression that I can see to get these dynamically by namespace, metric name, etc.

Once I have this value, I also need to create a metric for `instance count * threshold` and use this for the actual alarm. Am I using the wrong tool for this, is CloudWatch capable of this logic?

Comment: Can you comment as to whether the advice worked? Other people coming to the site will want to know how to fix the problem also

Answer (score 0):

So this hasn't been battle tested yet, but yes I believe you can accomplish this. And more so, I think it could be simpler than your current expectation.

Essentially, you would have your instances push a custom metric (which it looks like you're doing) to CloudWatch. Instead of triggering CloudWatch alarms for scaling events, you can actually write a TargetTrackingConfiguration in your ScalingPolicy with CloudFormation that will track the SUM of a metric.

For example:

```
ItemCountScalingPolicy:
  Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'
  Properties:
    TargetTrackingConfiguration:
      TargetValue: 30 #Or lower if you want runway for scaling events
      CustomizedMetricSpecification:
        Namespace: Custom
        Statistic: SUM #Takes care of the logic based on number of EC2 in ASG
        MetricName: EC2ItemCount
        Dimensions: #optional value that requires you to push data with the dimension
```

I believe this would create the namespace/metric for you (but I might be off). Now, the Scaling Policy will handle scale-in and out with the objective of staying close to that target. This could also be extended using CloudFormation's intrinsic functions to tie your metrics to the deployment. More modular and robust for your needs.

AWS CFN Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-policy.html#cfn-autoscaling-scalingpolicy-targettrackingconfiguration